# How to specialize a class template for vector?

Tags: c++, templates, vector, specialization

I am a bit confused about the syntax for template parameters...
How do i specalize this template:

```
template <typename T> class MyTemplate{
    public: 
        void doSomething(T){}
};
```

for std::vectors, i.e. I would to write something like

```
template <std::vector<typename T> > class MyTemplate{
    public:
        void doSomethingElse(std::vector<T>){}
};
```

to make the class behave differently, depending on whether the template parameter is just any type T or a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
template <typename T>
class MyTemplate<std::vector<T> > {
    ...
};
```

Comment: thank you. I knew that it has to be something simple but my IDEs "Unable to resolve Identifier" did not really help ;)